# How to get n x n covariance matrix for n arrays in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, covariance

For the following example code I am getting a 2x2 covariance matrix. How could I get a 3x3 covariance matrix instead?

```
a = [3,9,8,2]
b = [4,7,2,5]
c = [3,4,6,7]

cov_abc = np.cov(a,b,c)

print cov_abc
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
x = np.vstack([a,b,c])
cov = np.cov(x)
```

Comment: Thank you @Donbeo. Its quick and perfect. :)

Comment: Just `np.cov([a,b,c])` (without the call to vstack) seems to work too...

Comment: Hi @Donbeo, what about `a, b, c= np.random.normal(0, 1, [2,3])`